# tensorflow_cc results in Undefined reference to `omp_in_parallel@VERSION'

Tags: c++, linux, tensorflow, openmp, linker-errors

I installed `tensorflow-opt-cuda` on Arch linux, but trying to link as

```
g++ -fopenmp "CMakeFiles/intro-hello-world.dir/hello-world.cc.o" -o intro-hello-world /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so /usr/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so /usr/lib/libgomp.so -lpthread
```

results in:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so: undefined reference to `omp_in_parallel@VERSION'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_barrier@VERSION'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads@VERSION'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `kmp_set_blocktime@VERSION'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads@VERSION'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num@VERSION'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel@VERSION'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `omp_set_num_threads@VERSION'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

while I *do* have (for example):

```
readelf --symbols --wide /usr/lib/libgomp.so | grep 'omp_get_num_threads'
    79: 0000000000017110    29 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 omp_get_num_threads@@OMP_1.0
   202: 00000000000241b0     9 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 omp_get_num_threads_@@OMP_1.0
   329: 0000000000017110    29 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 gomp_ialias_omp_get_num_threads
   734: 00000000000241b0     9 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 omp_get_num_threads_
   851: 0000000000017110    29 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 omp_get_num_threads
```

Note that

```
readelf --symbols --wide /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so | grep 'omp_get_num_threads'
  1122: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND omp_get_num_threads@VERSION (42)
```

What is going on? Should this link, or not? And if not then who is to blame?

Comment: What is a reason of such unusual linkage `/usr/lib/libgomp.so` instead of `-lgomp` and other? Use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`, it enables more options requested for threads.

Comment: I think that this tensorflow_cc has been compiled with Intel KML and may be expecting Intel's OpenMP.

Comment: @273K I am using cmake to create my executable and this is how it generates the command to link (actually, it uses /usr/lib/libpthread.a instead of -lpthread , but since that doesn't influence the errors I replaced it manually with -lpthread to avoid drawing attention to using a static archine). I tried using -lgomp etc too, same result.

Comment: @ipapadop Yes, that turns out to be the case. However, after installing `intel-oneapi-openmp` and `intel-oneapi-compiler-shared-runtime-libs`, `/usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so.2` is still needing to link to `libomp.so` (as opposed to an expected libiomp5.so). It seems that a symlink from `libomp.so` to `/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libiomp5.so` is missing. Would you have an idea if that symlink is perhaps provided by a package that I am still missing?

Comment: Note that if I link directly with `-liomp5` then that works, but then it ALSO links with `/usr/lib/libomp.so` which is clearly not what we want (and deleting that, it just fails to link due to a missing libomp.so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Should this link, or not?

The linker errors are valid. When @VERSION is given, the symbol must have a literal "@VERSION" appended; it does not, so the symbols are not found.

### What is going on?

You are linking against the wrong library. The listed symbols are defined by `libiomp5.so`, not `libomp.so`. Install the packages `intel-oneapi-openmp` and `intel-oneapi-compiler-shared-runtime-libs` to get it.

### And if not then who is to blame?

Arch is to blame. First of all the dependency on `intel-oneapi-openmp` and `intel-oneapi-compiler-shared-runtime-libs` are missing.

Note, the latter is only necessary for the symbol link `/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest` (that in turn is pointed to by the symbolic link `/usr/share/pkgconfig/openmp.pc` which is owned by `intel-oneapi-openmp`. So that is another bug).

Worse, they do

```
find "${pkgdir}"/usr/lib -type f -exec patchelf --replace-needed libiomp5.so libomp.so '{}' \; -print
```

at the end of `_package()` in the `PKGBUILD` of tensorflow, see the repository `https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/tensorflow.git`

This causes the shared libraries to want to link to `libomp.so`, which is wrong.

Comment: I'm one of the maintainers of this package in Arch Linux. I pushed 2.15.0-2 with the suggested changes. Would appreciate some testers on this. The patchelf hack was a bit questionable anyway, in my opinion.

Comment: @svenstaro Thank you. I tried to reopen the issue that caused this hack to be added (which in my humble opinion isn't a hack, but an erroneous "fix" for something else that was broken for the person reporting that issue). The reaction was an email from a noreply email account saying that my reopen attempt was refused; I'd have to open a new issue with a minimal reproducable test case and stuff. I didn't obviously :P. So, I am glad you picked this up from here anyways. Nevertheless, I wish there had been more communication about this: in the meantime I made a lot of other changes to 
 PKGBUILD

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like to change? Our GitLab is now open for user contributions via merge requests. The tensorflow PKGBUILD is quite the sight so I always appreciate help there.

Comment: @svenstaro I created a gitlab account and cloned tensorflow. I am using a venv for python and I'm using bazelisk in my environment and currently just trying 'makepkg -s' on your repo in that environment.  I noted a `--config=v1` when compilation started, which slightly worries me (I'd think I definitely want version 2), but not even sure if that config also popped up in my own build, I'll have to try.

Comment: @svenstaro Another thing that I don't have is the "Get rid of hardcoded versions" sed; it seems those versions are important and we should just try to get it working with those version checks in place (that isn't too hard, really - you probably already do that). I also disagreed with the "Does tensorflow really need the compiler overridden in 5 places? Yes." .. my list there looks like:
export GCC_HOST_COMPILER_PATH=/opt/cuda/bin/gcc
And that's all - removed CC, CXX, HOST_C_COMPILER and HOST_CXX_COMPILER.

Comment: The `TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=sm_52,sm_53,sm_60,sm_61,sm_62,sm_70,sm_72,sm_75,sm_80,sm_86,sm_87,sm_89,sm_90,compute_90` worries me too a bit - I'm just using `export TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=sm_75` because I read that using more than what you need can use up quite some videocard RAM unnecessarily. Not sure if that can be avoided if you want to support EVERY card out there (though, starting at sm_70 maybe?)

Comment: I am using:
   "--config=opt"
   "--copt=-O3"
for BAZEL_ARGS, which should be a bash array - or you get problems when using spaces in argument.
Ie: export BAZEL_ARGS=( "--config=mkl" "--config=opt" ) and then when building you use ${BAZEL_ARGS[@]} and when building tmpoptcuda you can add --copt=-O3 for example. I am not sure CC_OPT_FLAGS is even honoured...
By the way, I am using `export CLANG_CUDA_COMPILER_PATH="$(which clang-16)"` for when clang is enabled. clang itself might not be version 16.

Comment: Under 'move extra headers to correct location' I have: local _site_packages="$(python -c 'import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])')"  and local _srch_path="${pkgdir}${_site_packages}"/tensorflow/include

Comment: There is more, but... where can I find your email, cause this is kinda not really working here :P

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you post this on our GitLab though? Ideally with a merge request and then we can discuss changes.